# Fill cell with text only if empty

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to make a program which will fill column A with specific text. The text will depend on whether cells B43 onwards are filled with the text I would like to show up in column A.

This is what I have come up with:

```
Dim freecell As Range
Dim inforcells As Range

Set infocells = Range("A61:A90")

If Range("B43") <> "" Then
        For Each freecell In infocells.Cells
            If freecell = "" Then
               freecell.Value = "some text"
            End If
        Exit For
        Next
End If

If Range("B45") <> "" Then
        For Each freecell In infocells.Cells
            If freecell = "" Then
               freecell.Value = "some text"
            End If
        Exit For
        Next
End If
```

How do I format the for loop outside of the if statement so that it not only checks for the next empty cell in column A but also fills it with the text I want?

Comment: to clarify your specification: Do you want to check for the value in B43, if there's any, then copy it to A61. After that the same procedure for B44 and A62 until A90 (B72)? Or do you want to fill every cell from A61 to A90 with the value of B43?

Comment: I think that "exit for" maybe removed or moved inside the "If freecell" statement. because the "For loop" will be execute only once.

Comment: I want to repeat the procedure from B43 & A61 to B72 & A90.

Comment: In that case, you can just use one loop that's iterating through both columns. I'll give an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code does what you desire:

```
Sub bla()
    Dim colAstart As Integer
    Dim colAend As Integer
    Dim totalRows As Integer
    Dim colBstart As Integer

    colAstart = 61
    colAend = 90

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To (colAend - colAstart + 1)
        If Cells(i + 42, 2) <> "" Then
            Cells(i + 60, 1) = Cells(i + 42, 2)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

You don't need range objects, just use the `Cells` property and check for content in the column "B" (2).